# .htaccess for multiple get parameters when the file or folder does not exist

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect an user call to a php script using .htaccess only when the requested file or folder do not exist. I achieved that with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ actions.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now, im trying to do the same but with two parameters, so if the user calls mysite.com/something/otherthing I should call actions with parameter1 and 2. I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ actions.php?lang=$1&username=$2 [QSA,L]
```

But it gave me an 404 error. What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT**:

As Volodymir suggested im using (.*)/(.*) to parse the url in the right way. I wonder if I can get a bit more complex rewrite. Im using the parameter one for the language and the second one as username. So:

mysite.com/en/user1 should call actions.php?lang=en&username=user1. That is working, but what happen if the language is not specified? mysite.com/user1, is there a way to fallback to en?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're catching only one variable in this regex:

```
^(.*)$
```

It should look like:

```
(.*)/(.*)/?$
```

And when you'll request URL kind of `mysite.com/something/otherthing`
You'll receive **something** in `$1` and **otherthing** in `$2`.

**UPD:** To see the difference between regular expressions with ending anchors and without:

```
123$ - matches everything ending with 123: 123, 123 but not 1234
123 - matches everything contains 123: 123, 1123, 1234 but not 1253
```

Comment: and the "$"? im verry noob in this, sorry if im asking for something dump

Comment: `$` is just the anchor to bind to the end of string, you can also add it.

Comment: thanks, but i realize that what i need its a bit more complex, can you please take a look on the edit?

Comment: In that case, you need to create another rule, but it should be preceded by condition for language existing

Comment: It should be something like this: `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ actions.php?lang=en&username=$1 [L]`